# How to get the tree produce by antlr 4 in prefix represention?

Tags: antlr4

I am using antlr 4 and I want to get the tree produce by antlr 4 in prefix represention ... the tree produce by antlr 4 is infix represtion But I wanted in prefix represtion ... so How I can do it ?

Comment: @Sam Harwell can help ?

Comment: The generated parse tree is neither prefix nor infix, as it is not a syntax tree. You have to walk over your parse tree and generate a syntax tree in a form you need.